# Updating Default List Model outside Event Dispatch Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, thread-safety

I'm trying to write an java application with GUI that allows users to connect to the server and challenge players from the list of players. Therefore, there must be EDT and other thread which is waiting for the invitation.

Now I have a problem when trying to refresh the user's table. This is button for refresh. When clicked, it just sends "REFR" to the server.

```
    class RefreshButton extends JButton implements ActionListener {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        PrintWriter outC;

        public RefreshButton(PrintWriter outC) {
            this.addActionListener(this);
            this.setText("Refresh");
            this.outC = outC;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            outC.println("REFR");
        }
    }
```

Now, there's this other thread, which listens to responds from the server. To avoid race, EDT only sends data (no reading from server in EDT) while the other handles all responses from the server.

```
    public void run() {

    while (true) {
        try {
                String c = inC.readLine();
                System.out.println(c);
                String[] cmd = c.split(" ");
                switch (cmd[0]) {
                case "INV":
                    int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                            "Do you accept challenge from " + cmd[1] + "?", "Challenge",
                            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                    if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                        ...
                    } else {
                        outC.println("NO");
                    }
                    break;
                case "REFR":
                    retrievePlayersList(inC);
                    break;
                case "DECL":
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Challenge declined");
                    break;
                ...
```

The method that should update the Default List Model, which is associated with JList in EDT.

```
    private static void retrievePlayersList(BufferedReader inC)
        throws IOException {
    String p = inC.readLine();      
    model.clear(); ///delete old data
    while (!p.equals("ENDlist")) {
        ...
        model.addElement(new Player(...));
        //DefaultListModel is assigned in constructor of the class (thread)
        p = inC.readLine();
    }
}
```

Sometimes, it works and sometimes, it does not. I understand that the problem is that addElement() is called outside the EDT. Could somebody please tell me, how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait() to add element to model. "invokeLatter" might not be the option for you. it depends on your application.

Comment: Thank you.

Actually, I used
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() { ...  })
and it worked.